# Why does a += a equals 0 in C?

Tags: c, loops

First of all sorry if this have been asked before, I tried looking for the answer but couldn't find it.

I'm a beginner studying C and while testing an infinite loop, I wrote the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int a = 1;

    for(;;)
    {
        printf("%d\n", a);
        a += a;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The output equals to a sequence of 0s, while I was expecting something like 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32...

But if I do:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int a = 1;

    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        printf("%d\n", a);
        a += a;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Just by including the loop control, it prints the result 1, 2, 4, 8, ..., 512. Can someone explain what's happening?

Comment: Change `i < 10` to `i < 40`, and all should become clear.

Comment: `The output equals to a sequence of 0s` You are missing the numbers in the beginning, that come before the 0s and match what you expected (up to the point of `int` overflow).

Comment: Wow I really forgot about that... Since the program runs so fast I didn't think about it. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you run the first program but pipe the results to more, you'll see 1, 2, 4, ... That is do

`./a.out | more`

The 0's are a result of integer overflow.